# DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE is overriden with django 2.2.6

Tags: python, django, httprequest, payload

I was using django 1.11.23 until last month and there was no DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE mentioned in my settings.py. It used to allow payloads of sizes far greater than the default value of 2.5MB. However, on switching to Django 2.2.6 and (djangorestframework upgraded from 3.9.1 to 3.10.3) it has suddenly started raising the "RequestDataTooBig" Exception. Now to run the same payloads, I am forced to add DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 *100 (after seeing multiple answers here). I also switched from python 2.7 to python 3.6.8 but that ideally should not be causing any issue. Why does it work in django 1.11.23 without this limit in the settings.py?

Comment: With framework updates come changes.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited. I want to know why the payload >2.5 MB was working in the previous version of django